# Use both default & postgres entity manager - Symfony 6.4

Tags: symfony6

I tried to use both default & postgres entity manager in my project. I configured them in the 'doctrine.yaml' file which looks like:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    connections:
        default:
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '8.0.36'
            charset: 'UTF8'
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            logging: true
        postgres:
            driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
            server_version: '10'
            charset: 'UTF8'
            url: '%env(resolve:POSTGRES_DATABASE_URL)%'
            logging: true
    
    default_connection: default

orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: attribute
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                    alias: App
        postgres:
            connection: postgres
            mappings:
                AppPostgres:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: attribute
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/PostgresSQL'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\PostgresSQL'
                    alias: AppPostgres
```

When I run the command 'debug:autowiring', it shows the entity managers like:

```
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface - alias:doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface $defaultEntityManager - alias:doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface $postgresEntityManager - alias:doctrine.orm.postgres_entity_manager
```

I tried to connect the postgres_entity_manager in the repository using the below code:

```
$this->getEntityManager('postgres')
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM postgres_table';
$nativeQuery = $postgresConnection->createNativeQuery($sql, new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping());
$result = $nativeQuery->getResult();
```

It always connect only the 'default entity manager'. Even I tried to pass the default & postgres through the getManger() but it connects only with the default entity manager.

How should I connect the different entity managers in the repository files?

**Note:**
I have so many repository files. I need to use both default & postgres entity managers in some repository files. Most of the tables in the postgres don't have entity files. I just want to fetch data from the postgres tables by "select" queries.

I followed the symfony documentation at [here](https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) but I can't understand it clearly. Any help would be appreciated.